# CSS alignment and margin issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a top nav bar. However, I can't seem to fix some minor issues with my CSS. Issues:

1. There is a margin at the top of the button (some extra blue before the black). How do I get rid of this?
2. I am not able to center my text. When I try to use the `text-align` tag in `navbar` it also affects the button's position. On the other hand if I try to put the text in it's own `div` or `p` it goes to the next line / can't been seen in the bar.
3. In the same idea as the previous point. How would I add another button just like the one on the left but on the right? If I had a button with `margin-left: calc(100%-45);` I think I would face similar formatting issues.

Would very much appreciate it if someone could help me with these issues.

```css
.menuBtn{
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:inherit;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:24px;
  width: 45px!important;
  height: 45px!important;
  background-size: contain;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-top: 0!important;
   background-color: black;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00baff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000000000000;
  height: 45px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
  max-height: 45px!important;
  margin-top: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<button id="menuBtn" class="menuBtn">☰</button>
SOME TITLE
</div>
```

Comment: The space is caused by `display: inline-block` on the `<button>`. Changing to `display: block` would probably solve your issue.

Comment: that fixes the issue with the button but causes the title to disappear. I'm guessing it's moved to next line.

Comment: just u want to remove extra blue before the menu btn ? @AntersBear

Comment: and center the text "SOME TITLE"

Comment: you have already "height: 45px!important;" rule for the button. why do you need "vertical-align: middle;" for it. Remove "vertical-align" will help you

Comment: @MuratAras this change doesn't do anything :(

Comment: u want to remove extra blue before the menu btn ,align some title in center and u want to have a another button just like the one on the left but on the right these three things u r expecting i'am right? @AntersBear

Comment: what about "vertical-align:top;" on ".menuBtn" class?

Comment: Flexbox will help you position elements correctly. Try this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.menuBtn{
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:inherit;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:24px;
  width: 45px!important;
  height: 45px!important;
  background-size: contain;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0!important;
  background-color: black;
}
.menuBtn1 {
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:inherit;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:24px;
  width: 45px!important;
  float:right;
  height: 45px!important;
  background-size: contain;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin:0px;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00baff;
  position: fixed;
  text-align:center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000000000000;
  height: 45px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
  max-height: 45px!important;
  margin-top: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="navbar">

    <button id="menuBtn" class="menuBtn">☰</button>
    SOME TITLE

    <button id="menuBtn" class="menuBtn1">☰</button>

    </div>
</body>
```